# Can a Boggart affect another Boggart?

Tags: harry-potter

Can a boggart affect another? Or, more generally, can they affect non-human beings?

I can't quite remember if this is addressed in the books (I've never read *Fantastic Beasts and where to find them*). If so, what form would they take?

Comment: Boggarts don't appear in "Fantastic Beasts", presumably because they aren't beasts

Comment: I never read any canon about this, but 1+ anyway due to possible interesting answers. It might be on pottermore, you should try there.

Comment: There's nothing on pottermore that answers this question

Comment: Why the downvotes? Perfectly legitimate and interesting question

Comment: I don't have any references, but my guess is that a Boggart can affect some non-human beings that can have fear; but that a Boggart most likely won't affect another Boggart, either because it is immune to its own type of magic, or because it recognizes others of its kind and will not attack them.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question:

***Probably yes.*** ***This was never addressed in the books or elsewhere.***

Here are my theory's based on Pottermore, the site said that Boggarts are non-beings..

From Pottermore

> The more generally fearful a person is, the more susceptible they will
>   be to Boggarts. **Mugggles, too, feel their presence and may even**
>   **glimpse them, although they seem less capable of seeing them plainly**
>   and are usually easily convinced that the Boggart was a figment of
>   their imagiantion.
>
> Like a poltergeist, **a Boggart is not and never has been truly alive.**
>   It is one of the strange non-beings that populate the magical world,
>   for which there is no equivalent in the muggle realm. **Boggarts can be**
>   **made to disappear, but more Boggarts will inevitably arise to take**
>   their place. Like poltergeists and the more sinister Dementors, they
>   **seem to be generated and sustained by human emotions.**

I have never read anything canon about this and it is not in any other literature if I am not mistaken.

Here is my theories based on canon:

1. If a boggart saw itself it could possibly just turn into regular form. I mean when we are alone we behave normally, we don't affect ourselves or anything. So the Boggart could possibly do the same, its in a relax atmosphere so why do anything?
2. The Boggart could get scared. A lot of animals get scared when seeing themselves(in the mirror), so the Boggart could possibly get scared and die or try to change or something. Or they could get hopelessly confused and just change shape rapidly. Lupin did say that it was best to travel in pairs around them as that confuses them. So maybe having no fear confuses them.
3. The Boggart could cease living when it gets in the presence of the same matter.
4. The Boggart could become nothing. I mean the Boggart is always turning into something so I think it would make sense if the Boggart was scared of nothing or becoming nothing, so to scare each other they would turn into nothing.

The theory I put the most stock into is #1. 1# makes the most sense to me, but then I could be wrong. A lot of antisocial(to humans) creatures don't attack their own kind. I mean take Dementors, Thestrals, Unicorns, etc. They don't seem to want to attack each other so that rules out that.

***Things they would do around non-human beings.***

It is not known. But I would hazard to guess that they would scare them as well. I mean creatures that are sentient or have a humans level of consciousness would be fair game(centaurs, etc). I would say that a Boggarts ability to shape shift is like a Jellyfish's tentacles, a squid's ink, or a dog's teeth's it is purely defensive. And since it has to be defensive against everyone that is capable of hurting it it would affect a dog, whale or other animal. I say hurt, but if that is not possible I would say scare it.

But then again it might do nothing as Pottermore said:

> they seem to be generated and sustained by human emotions.
>
> "So the boggart sitting in the darkness within has not yet assumed a
>   form. He does not yet know what will frighten the person on the other
>   side of the door. **Nobody knows what a boggart looks like when he is
>   alone**, but when I let him out, he will immediately become whatever
>   each of us most fears."

Professor Lupin to his Third year class in 1993.

[Definition](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Boggart)

> A boggart is an amortal shape-shifting non-being that takes on the
>   form of the viewer's worst fear. When facing a boggart, it is best to
>   have someone else along, to try to confuse it, since facing more than
>   one person at once would make it indecisive as to what form it must
>   take, usually a mixed-up amalgam of the victims' fears. Because of
>   their shape-shifting ability, no one knows what a boggart looks like
>   when it is alone,........

Things they might do:

1. Attack each other with something. But I think they are non-being so that rules that out.
2. Change rapidly.
3. Explode.
4. Get scared and flee.
5. Change into nothing.
6. Change into their true form.

Answer (score 1):

"What kills a boggart is laughter". We can infer that boggarts would be scared of laughter (If they had any feelings at all). So if two boggarts came face to face then one either on of them could turn into the sound of laughter thereby killing themselves and the boggart in front of them (this might be why there were never more than one boggart at a time in a particular place). As far as other non humans are concerned we can apply the same logic. Boggart will take the form of the entity's( that is standing in front of it) fear. So if a dementor approached a boggart then the boggart would turn into a patronus. If the boggart approached an animal then the boggart would take the shape of the hunter of that animal and so on and so forth.